# An alternative to 'political manifesto'

Tags: synonyms

I'm writing a list of political policies, which I'd like to see the government enact.

On my blog where I'll publish it, I don't want to call it a *political manifesto* because... that word has associations with political kooks who blow buildings up.

Is there an alternative phrase or word I can use?

Comment: How about "tract" or "treatise"?

Comment: "_political manifesto_  ... that word has associations with political kooks who blow buildings up." There are millions of Google hits for "labour + "manifesto" and "conservative" + "manifesto", and these are the terms used on TV etc. 'List' has associations with sinking ships. All words have associations.

Comment: @Silenus Both of these are good enough to post as an answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My thoughts entirely. Perhaps the OP should enlighten the editors of the OED about the "political kooks who blow buildings up" - they don't appear to know that the word carries such connotations! And careful about talking about *millions* - the word has associations with genocide!

Comment: "Platform" is often used for an organized party or other group.  "Statement of belief" is often used by a group when expressing a philosophical stance.  And there are always words like "proclamation" which can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I like the following:

1. *tract*
2. *treatise*
3. *pamphlet*

Answer (score 1):

Communiqué (as in Shanghai)
Creed (as in Apostles')
Declaration (as in Independence)
Edict (as in Milan)
Proclamation (as in Emancipation)
Theses (a la Luther)

Comment: There is also Program or Programme (as in Gotha).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the definition of *[manifesto](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manifesto)* has anything to do with violence or fringe movements, and I tend to think those connotations are found mainly among Americans, where the term is not commonly used except when referring to the so-called *[Unabomber Manifesto](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/national/longterm/unabomber/manifesto.text.htm)* by terrorist Ted Kaczynski (and like documents) or to Marx's *[Communist Manifesto](http://avalon.law.yale.edu/subject_menus/mancont.asp)*. Neither of them has ever gained much currency here.

Indeed, the latter was published originally as *The Manifesto of the Communist Party*, being a statement of the principles and objectives of the communists. That is what parties do, like those radical democrats in the [BJP](http://www.bjp.org/manifesto2014), the proletarian redistributionists of South Africa's [Democratic Alliance](http://www.da.org.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/DA-Manifesto-2014.pdf), or for that matter the zany revolutionaries of the UK's [Conservative Party](https://www.conservatives.com/manifesto). And even if those fluffy bleeding-hearts of Australia's Liberal Party no longer use the word for their document, the [BBC does](http://www.bbc.com/news/election-2015-32301469). (For the uninitiated, these are all major center-right mainstream/non-revolutionary political parties in major democracies).

---

If you are declaring the principles and policy goals of a (new or existing) political movement or organization for a North American audience, you might do well with *[platform](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platform)*, as Merriam-Webster says:

> 2. a declaration of the principles on which a group of persons stands; especially:  a declaration of principles and policies adopted by a political party or a candidate

Canadian and American political parties, with one or two exceptions, issue *platforms*. This is true not only of [Democrats](https://www.democrats.org/party-platform) and [Republicans](https://www.gop.com/platform/), or regional entities like the the [PQ](http://pq.org/plateforme/) and the [PP](http://www.prohibitionists.org/background/party_platform/body_party_platform.html), but also of fringe-y groups one might suspect of wanting to issue manifestoes, from the [Christian Liberty Party](https://sites.google.com/site/christianlibertyparty/platform) to the [Justice Party](http://www.justicepartyusa.org/platform).

---

If you are not writing on behalf of a movement or organization, you might be simply presenting a *plan*, but without concrete policy goals and a way to achieve them, it is simply a set of ideas, which could be organized as a *treatise*, listed as *tenets*, declaimed in a *proclamation*, recited as a *credo*, or simply declared as a *declaration*.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it your (proposed) **policy agenda**.

[Agenda - dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/agenda)

> a list, plan, outline, or the like, of things to be done, matters to be acted or voted upon, etc.